# Is there a way to turn off code completion in Mono Develop?

Tags: monodevelop

Is there a way to turn off code completion in Mono Develop?
I'm using Version 2.8.6.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the "Text Editor->General" panel and uncheck "Enable Code Completion".

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are hitting the [bug described here](http://codethatworks.blogspot.com/2009/10/how-to-fix-monodevelop-code-completion.html), the solution is *not* to disable code completion. Rather, the solution is as follows:

1. Close MonoDevelop
2. Open the Terminal application
3. Run this command: rm
   -r ~/.config/MonoDevelop/CodeCompletionData
4. Restart MonoDevelop

Comment: Actually I want the opposite.  It's working fine for me, but when I use monodevelop over ssh with X11 forwarding it just slows things down  and I want to turn it off at times.  Maybe I could corrupt the cache? :)

Comment: At least with MonoDevelop 5, you can delete the folder `~/.cache/Monodevelop-5.0`.